# React Dynamic Form with React State

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

So i need to create a form in react with dynamics fields , these fields are elements in an Array ,
so i have to create an Object (which is a state using useState hook) from the Form , and the fields should be the properties of this object , my code :

```
const [object, setObject] = useState({})

const onChange = e => {
        setObject({...object,[e.target.name]:e.target.value})
    }

const properties = ["to","placeFrom","placeTo","from","date"]

  {properties.length !== 0 && 
        
        <form>

            {properties.map(property => 

<input type="text" class="form-control" name={property} value={object.property} onChange={onChange}/>

                )}

        </form> 
    }
```

The Object in state should be like this :

```
{
to: value,
placeFrom: value,
placeTo: value,
from: value,
date: value,
}
```

the problem is in the value attribute in the input , i couldn't make it dynamic too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you are accessing the `object` state when setting the `value` for the `<input/>`.

By doing `object.property`, you are asking javascript to provide the value associated with the `property` key on the object. That would return a value if your state object was of the form:

```
{
  property: 'some-value'
}
```

In this case there is no key in your state called `property` and this is not the intended behavour.

To access the `object` dynamically with the variable `property`, you can do this: `object[property]`.

Thus your input would look like

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name={property} value={object[property]} onChange={onChange}/>
```

I might also suggestion that instead of calling your state `object`, you could provide a more descriptive name like `formValueState` or something like that.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you ! that was exactly what i needed , i didn't know that you could do that in the value property of the input, Many thanks!